# Critical spaces in Navier-Stokes theory of well posedness

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, linear-pde

It is striking that the local in time existence of solution to incompressible 3D  Navier-Stokes equations depends
only on properties of solutions of the heat equation; such a result holds in more
general critical spaces, see, for example, the nice review article by Cannone   "Harmonic Analysis Tools for Solving
the Incompressible Navier–Stokes Equations". My question is: for what reasons this is in fact true? Why this exclusive dependence on solutions of Heat equation?